# Can you combine CSS declarations?

Tags: css, sass

You can combine CSS **selectors** by using a comma, such as in the following example:

```css
.one, .two {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
```

This has the same result as specifying the two selectors independently:

```css
.one {
  color: #F00;
}
.two {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
```

Combining selectors as above is incredibly useful, as it means that you only have to worry about changing one value if you want to alter multiple elements. This comes in really handy for colour scheme changes.

But is it possible to combine CSS **declarations**?

For example, let's say I'm trying to vertically centralise text in an element, where `line-height` should always equal `height`:

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

The expected combined declaration of `height, line-height: 100px;` doesn't apply either declaration, raising an invalid property value.

In SASS, it would be possible to make `line-height` dependent on `height` with something as simple as:

```
$height = 100px;

.test {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: $height;
  line-height: $height;
}
```

Is there any way to specify that one property should utilise the same value from another property with raw CSS?

Comment: In short you'd want [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), but working ? In the general case you're out of luck if you don't use a css preprocessor or javascript. That's why scss, less, etc. exist: they add features that aren't in raw CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can:

```css
:root {
--height: 100px;
}
.test {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: var(--height);
  line-height: var(--height);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

But not all browsers support CSS variables - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I wasn't aware of CSS variables other than functions like `calc()`. Thank you :)